# How to make RHEL look at access.conf for su -?

Tags: ssh, rhel, pam

I use the file `/etc/security/access.conf` to dictate what users have access to the server:

```
+ : root : LOCAL
+ : user1 : ALL
+ : user2 : ALL
+ : user3 : ALL
- : ALL : ALL
```

This works fine for new SSH sessions. Only these 3 users have access to the server via SSH. Unfortunately after logging in they can use `su -` to switch to all other users.

How can I make `su -` also pay attention to the `/etc/security/access.conf` file so that user1/2/3 are the only users that can actually be used via SSH?

Comment: @ujjan have you tested with that pam related changes ?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make su - also pay attention to the
>   /etc/security/access.conf

You need to add following entry in `/etc/pam.d/su`, in order to use `/etc/security/access.conf` for `su -`

```
session required pam_access.so
```

**Man pam_access**

> The pam_access PAM module is mainly for access management. It provides
>   logdaemon style login access control based on login names, host or
>   domain names, internet addresses or network numbers, or on terminal
>   line names in case of non-networked logins.
>
> By default rules for access management are taken from config file
>   /etc/security/access.conf if you don't specify another file

Comment: Very close, but you want to add it as `session required pam_access.so`, not `account`.

Comment: @Patrick thanks can you look at this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/openssh-root-user-account-restriction-revisited.html

Comment: It works for ssh because ssh requires the ability to look up information about the account. You'll get a few warnings from `su` if you add it as `account required`, but `su` will still work.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make `su -` also pay attention to the `/etc/security/access.conf` file so that user1/2/3 are the only users that can actually be used via SSH?

`su` is actually paying attention to your `/etc/security/access.conf`. The problem is just that as soon as these users have opened a shell after having logged in via SSH, they are in fact local. Just the fact that they are using SSH to access the machine doesn't make their sessions any different from a local login on a TTY.

I don't think that you can or should prevent them from running `su`. Sure, you could try to limit read/execute permissions to `su` to prevent them from running it, but this will probably break stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method that employs the use of the `wheel` group.

1. Add user to wheel group

   ```
   $ sudo usermod -G wheel user1
   ```
2. Edit pam su file

   ```
   $ sudo  vim /etc/pam.d/su
   ```
3. Make this line look like one of the following

   ```
   auth required /lib/security/pam_wheel.so use_uid

   -or-

   auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid
   ```

#### Example

On my Fedora 14 system the `/etc/pam.d/su` file was like this:

```
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth       required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

So simply uncommenting that line made it so that only users in the `wheel` group could access the `su` command.

#### should you do this?

I would probably encourage you to not do it this way. You might want to explore the use of `sudo` if users have a need to become other users.